# Dart, use SSL emitted by an authority

Tags: ssl, dart, certutil

I create a db with certutil

```
myproject/bin/pkcert
echo "dartdart" > pwdfile
certutil -N -d 'sql:./' -f pwdfile
```

Then, I import my certificate validated by an authority

```
certutil -d "sql:./" -A -t "C,C,C" -n "my_cert" -i certificate.crt
```

I check if it work

```
certutil -L -d 'sql:./'
Certificate Nickname                                         Trust Attributes
                                                             SSL,S/MIME,JAR/XPI

my_cert                                                      C,C,C
```

My main.dart

```dart
library main;

import "dart:io";

void main() {
  var testPkcertDatabase = Platform.script.resolve('./pkcert')
                                   .toFilePath();
  SecureSocket.initialize(database: testPkcertDatabase,
                          password: 'dartdart');

  HttpServer
      .bindSecure(InternetAddress.ANY_IP_V6,
                  8443,
                  certificateName: 'my_cert')
      .then((server) {
        server.listen((HttpRequest request) {
          request.response.write('Hello, world!');
          request.response.close();
        });
      });
}
```

I execute, and I get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: CertificateException: Cannot find server certificate by nickname: my_cert (OS Error: security library: read-only database., errno = -8126)
```

I missed something or I should report a bug?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add `-s "cn=mycert"` to

```
certutil -d "sql:./" -A -t "C,C,C" -n "my_cert" -i certificate.crt
```

and use it with

```dart
HttpServer
  .bindSecure(InternetAddress.ANY_IP_V6,
              8443,
              certificateName: 'CN=my_cert')
```

as shown in this blog post http://jamesslocum.com/post/70003236123 ?